# exec awk {{if($1-$2>20) print}} file

Tags: awk, tcl

Not able to execute expression in inside if statement while using awk. Please help.

command:

```
exec awk {{if($1-$2>20) print}} file
```

where field 1 and 2 contains numeric digits.

Comment: Please elaborate on "not able". Do you get an error? The command you showed works fine for me.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13: The question is tagged with tcl, meaning the OP is running the command from Tcl. Then exec is a reasonable way to invoke an external command like awk.

Comment: @SchelteBron, ok sure, thank you for letting me know, I will delete my comment now, cheers.

Comment: @reshma, you'll need to provide some sample contents of `file`, and show what the output of that exec command is, and also show what output you expect to see. Refer to [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Specifically, what exact error message do you see? The code sample you pasted is not obviously wrong in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine, you'll have to provide more details:

```sh
$ cat file
40 10 yes
40 30 no
20 0 no
21 0 yes

$ awk '{if($1 - $2 > 20) print}' file
40 10 yes
21 0 yes
```

then

```
$ tclsh
% exec awk {{if($1 - $2 > 20) print}} file
40 10 yes
21 0 yes
```

Note that your awk program can be written as (shell quoting here)

```sh
awk '$1 - $2 > 20' file
```